# Graph API Javascript bug

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph, facebook-access-token

Recently I am experiencing this problem.

When I click to register with facebook and I am logged in as a user, I can see my information correctly. But staying on the same page, if I log out from facebook in some other tab and click Register with facebook on my own site, I see this person profile picture. The url of this image is:
http://graph.facebook.com/undefined/picture?type=large

I am accessing graph API using APP

Kindly advise me the solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a users data `requires an access token`, with out this token your call is getting **undefined** returned as a user, and with out the access token appended to the picture url it returns *emphamous* `Unknown User`.

refer to: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
for requesting access tokens, and usage.

Example Only:  `https://graph.facebook.com/ShawnsSpace/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1&access_token=users_access_token`

Comment: FB.login(function(response) 
  {     
    //If the user is succesfully authenticated, we execute some code to handle the freshly
    //logged in user, if not, we do nothing
if (response.authResponse) 
    {

        FB.api('/me', function(response) {}
}

        {scope:'email,user_events,friends_photos,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_location,user_location,user_relationships'}); });//fbclick

Answer (score 0):

My script cannot access FB script without Access token

```
FB.login(function(response) 
  {     
    //If the user is succesfully authenticated, we execute some code to handle the freshly
    //logged in user, if not, we do nothing
if (response.authResponse) 
    {

        FB.api('/me', function(response) {}
}

        {scope:'email,user_events,friends_photos,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_hometown,user_location,user_location,user_relationships'}); });//fbclick
```

So, I think access token condition is already satisfied.